# Trying to make an out of tree module but get stuck when I test it.(make test)

Tags: python, gnuradio

I'm trying to install an out of tree module for my gnuradio and I'm following a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BW8o9ZgFJ5I&t=540s. However once I get to testing the code it keeps finding errors that I can't seem to find.

It shows me this when I put `make test`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/gr-NRZI_decode/build$ make test
Running tests...
Test project /home/ubuntu/gr-NRZI_decode/build
    Start 1: test_NRZI_decode
1/2 Test #1: test_NRZI_decode .................   Passed    0.02 sec
    Start 2: qa_square_ff
2/2 Test #2: qa_square_ff .....................***Failed    0.46 sec

50% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 2

Total Test time (real) =   0.49 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      2 - qa_square_ff (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
Makefile:85: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 8
```

They when I try to zero in on the problem with `ctest -V -R qa_square_ff` I get this:

```
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/home/ubuntu/gr-NRZI_decode/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/home/ubuntu/gr-NRZI_decode/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Test project /home/ubuntu/gr-NRZI_decode/build
Constructing a list of tests
Done constructing a list of tests
Updating test list for fixtures
Added 0 tests to meet fixture requirements
Checking test dependency graph...
Checking test dependency graph end
test 2
    Start 2: qa_square_ff

2: Test command: /bin/sh "/home/ubuntu/gr-NRZI_decode/build/python/qa_square_ff_test.sh"
2: Test timeout computed to be: 9.99988e+06
2: E
2: ======================================================================
2: ERROR: test_001_square_ff (__main__.qa_square_ff)
2: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
2: Traceback (most recent call last):
2:   File "/home/ubuntu/gr-NRZI_decode/python/qa_square_ff.py", line 40, in test_001_square_ff
2:     self.tb.connect(src,sqr)
2:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/hier_block2.py", line 47, in wrapped
2:     func(self, src, src_port, dst, dst_port)
2:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/hier_block2.py", line 110, in connect
2:     self.primitive_connect(*args)
2:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/runtime_swig.py", line 5307, in primitive_connect
2:     return _runtime_swig.top_block_sptr_primitive_connect(self, *args)
2: ValueError: itemsize mismatch: vector_source_f1:0 using 4, square_ff1:0 using 1
2: 
2: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
2: Ran 1 test in 0.000s
2: 
2: FAILED (errors=1)
1/1 Test #2: qa_square_ff .....................***Failed    0.19 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.19 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      2 - qa_square_ff (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
```

Here is my code for `qa_square_ff.py`:

```
from gnuradio import gr, gr_unittest
from gnuradio import blocks
import NRZI_decode_swig as NRZI_decode

class qa_square_ff (gr_unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp (self):
        self.tb = gr.top_block ()

    def tearDown (self):
        self.tb = None

    def test_001_square_ff(self):
        src_data=(1,2,3,4,5)
    expected_data=(1,4,9,16,25)
    src=blocks.vector_source_f(src_data)
    sqr=NRZI_decode.square_ff()
    dst=blocks.vector_sink_f()
    self.tb.connect(src,sqr)
    self.tb.connect(sqr,dst)
        self.tb.run ()
    result_data=dst.data()
    self.assertCharTuplesAlmostEqual(expected_data,result_data,6)
        # check data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gr_unittest.run(qa_square_ff, "qa_square_ff.xml")
```

Comment: This question may be out of the depth of most of us at AskUbuntu. You may be better off on StackOverflow or ServerFault. It is likely solving this will require a deeper knowledge of software installation or python programming than is common on AskUbuntu.